# Cancelling notifications for app updates

Tags: cyanogenmod, notifications

Every time an app automatically updates, it shows a notification. I find this ridiculous. For me, a notification means "something I should be notified about". The thought that I should be made aware every time a random app I never use gets updated from version 1.5.2 to 1.5.3 is so ludicrous that it makes me want to sit back in my reclining chair, take the backrest all the way down and think about how big the universe is and how small our lives are.

Is there any way to make Android not show those notifications?

(Note: I use CyanogenMod 9.)

Comment: I might suggest that the problem is less the notifications, and more that you need some counselling.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to CM10 if you can - you can then adjust notifications on a per-app basis.

Note though, that for your problem, the only way to prevent " xxx app has been updated" notifications might be to disable the Play Store from showing notifications, which IMHO isn't a good idea.

[image]

Comment: Why would it not be a good idea? Sounds like exactly what the OP wants. Coupled with the "Update over Wi-Fi only" Play Store setting (so you know you're not sucking valuable bandwidth when you're out and about) and the fact that permissions changes require manual update, it's pretty easy to just let Play Store do its thing.

Comment: I don't see how this is a solution to my problem. I want to stop notifications about app updates for all apps, and I don't want to stop notifications for the Play store app.

Comment: @RamRachum Something has got to give. You can't disable notifications from an app and still expect to be notified at the same time - it's a global option.

Comment: @KeithS - Personally, I never allow apps to auto-update. I always read the comments prior to allowing a working app to update (in case others are facing difficulties with the new update). Also, if you encounter some behaviour that's out of the ordinary or something like abnormal battery usage, it's easier to narrow down the culprit if you know which apps have recently been changed/updated.

Comment: What exactly does the Play Store notify you about besides updates? What notifications would you be missing out on by disabling them for the Play Store? I genuinely cannot think of anything. I suppose you'd lose confirmation that apps are being downloaded and are installing, but you don't sound like the kind of person who would care about that.